# Issue With Planck Function Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, astronomy

We are looking to plot the entirety of Plancks function from Temperatures 5000K-10,000K.

I have tried various ways to fix the graphing issue, but it appears my formatting or something of the sort has resulted in a mixed array value, which I cant find the solution for

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#all constants
h=6.62e-34
c=2.998e8
k=1.3806503E-23

pi=np.pi


#equation
def planck(lamb1,T):
    top=(2*h*c**2)/lamb1**5
    bottom_hard=h*c/(lamb1*k*T)
    Flux=top/((math.e**(bottom_hard)-1))
    return Flux
# function inputs
lamb1=np.arange(0.1,10.1,.01)
Flux1=(lamb1*1e-6,5000)
Flux2=(lamb1*1e-6,6000)
Flux3=(lamb1*1e-6,7000)
Flux4=(lamb1*1e-6,8000)
Flux5=(lamb1*1e-6,9000)
Flux6=(lamb1*1e-6,10000)

#Actual plot

#data
wl = np.arange(10e-5, 10e-7,0.01*1e-6)

plt.plot(wl,Flux1)
plt.plot(wl,Flux2)
plt.plot(wl,Flux3)
plt.plot(wl,Flux4)
plt.plot(wl,Flux5)
plt.plot(wl,Flux6)
plt.xlabel("Wavelength(m)")
plt.ylabel("Flux(Vm)")
plt.title("Plancks Function Curve for Temp Ranges 5000K-10,000K")
plt.show()
```

The error I get is

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (2,)
```

I just need to get the actual graph data to work. Once done, I can do the rest of the edits myself (hopefully!!)

Comment: Typically, it's helpful to share more of the stack trace, so people can see on what line the error occurred. However, I'm guessing it's on the first `plot` line `plt.plot(wl,Flux1)` since `wl` is a range of a 1000 values, while `Flux1` (you shouldn't use capitals here, by the way) is a pair of two values, clearly not the same dimensions.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `Flux1=(lamb1*1e-6,5000)` does? Because it seems to me that this is where your issue is. You're defining a tuple, where you appear to want to define a series of values. Isn't this just a typo and did you mean to write `Flux1=planck(lamb1*1e-6,5000)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a type and meant to define `Flux1 = planck(...)`, the problem resides in the way you define `wl`.

```
wl = np.arange(10e-5, 10e-7,0.01*1e-6)
```

means that you make an array with values bigger than `10e-5` and smaller than `10e-7`. There are none! If instead, you define

```
wl = np.arange(0.1*10e-6, 10.1*10e-6,0.01*1e-6)
```

you can then plot

```
plt.plot(wl, Fluz1)
```